# Counting number of digits in a number in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, x86, numbers, glibc

I need to count the number of decimal digits in a number(for ex: 4 for 1002). I want to do this in O(1) time complexity as the code shall be iterated over huge set of numbers, significantly saving cpu time.

I have come up with two solutions:

1. Divide by 10 in a loop till the number becomes zero. Loop count is
   the answer. But, it is obviously O(n) time.
2. `log_base_10(num) + 1`

The question: Is log10 an O(1) solution? I am running the code with glibc on an x86 machine. How is that implemented under the hood? and, are there better solutions for this?

Comment: what is the upper limit for the number? Or there is no such limit?

Comment: Solution 1 is *O(log n)* not *O(n)* and, assuming your number is a `long` or an `int` (not a bignum), might be faster than solution 2.

Comment: You actually want `1 + floor(log(N)/log(10))`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Number of digits in that number is the input set. For a n digit number, loop has to execute n times. Then, it is O(n), right? Am i missing something?

Comment: @paraneec linear time in the number of bits is logarithmic time in the magnitude of the represented number.

Comment: @paraneec: the 'n' is based on input not output

Comment: Your question seems odd. Do you really want to know the computational complexity, or just the fastest way to get the "length in decimal representation"?

Comment: @izomorphius : They are `unsigned long` integers. The digit count is expected to go to maximum.

Comment: @harold: I want the complexity of log10 function in glibc/x86 environment. Also, wanted to if there is a better solution than log10, if exists.

Comment: Don't forget that the O notation doesn't tell you how long an algorithm will take, it only tells you how the execution time scales with different sized inputs. The only way to determine if an implementation of an O(log n) algorithm is actually faster than an implementation of an O(n) algorithm is to use a profiler.

Comment: If your numbers are of a fixed size, big-O notation is pretty meaningless. As @Skizz points out, there's no implicit reason that an O(log n) algorithm has to be faster than an O(n) algorithm for a given value of n.

Comment: A much faster O(n) would be to start with `threshold=1` and multiply it by `10` in a loop, comparing each iteration.  Then your loop-carried dependency is only 2 or 3 cycles for integer multiply, not ~10 to 15 for integer division (or much worse for 64-bit integer division on some CPUs.)  Or binary-search in a table of powers of 10.  Or brute-force linear search with SIMD.  But probably the bit-scan answer to find log2(x) and then check is good.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use log to solve this problem as it involves double calculation and may turn out to be slower then the cycle by dividing by 10. Sacrificing some memory and some time for precomputation you may have an answer in a few integer instructions. For instance precompute the number of digits of the numbers up to 10 000:

```
int num_digits[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    num_digits[i] = 1;
  } else if (i < 100) {
    num_digits[i] = 2;
  } else if (i < 1000) {
    num_digits[i] = 3;
  }
}
```

And now here is how you get the number of digits of a number in about 4 integer operations:

```
int get(int n) {
  int result = 0;
  while (n > 10000) {
    result += 4;
    n /= 10000;
  }
  return result + num_digits[n];
}
```

This of course sacrifices memory for speed but as we know [there is no free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming unsigned integer and Intel platform (BSR instruction), you can get the highest set bit. Then you know:

```
2^i <= num < 2^(i+1)
```

where `i` is the highest set bit of the `num`. So simple lookup table (indexed by `i`) limits you to two possible decimal digit counts and that can be resolved by just single if.

But do you really use so large numbers you need such unportable optimization?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case for [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10Obvious)

```
unsigned int v; // non-zero 32-bit integer value to compute the log base 10 of 
int r;          // result goes here

r = (v >= 1000000000) ? 9 : (v >= 100000000) ? 8 : (v >= 10000000) ? 7 : 
    (v >= 1000000) ? 6 : (v >= 100000) ? 5 : (v >= 10000) ? 4 : 
    (v >= 1000) ? 3 : (v >= 100) ? 2 : (v >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
```

"This method works well when the input is uniformly distributed over 32-bit values because 76% of the inputs are caught by the first compare, 21% are caught by the second compare, 2% are caught by the third, and so on (chopping the remaining down by 90% with each comparision). As a result, less than 2.6 operations are needed on average."

Comment: It's probably a close thing between this and a fild/fyl2x/fist due to the number of conditional branches in the above code.

Comment: @Skizz: I'd guess some compilers would choose to make a branchless chain of compare/cmov, especially if profile-guideded feedback showed branching predicted poorly.  (If you were branching, small numbers are common so checking them first would make more sense for some use-cases.  But if your numbers are uniformly distributed across `uint32_t`, most of them will have 9 digits, and the vast majority will have 8 or 9, so checking larger numbers first makes sense for that.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
1 + floor(log(N)/log(10))
```

(This will not work on 0. If you input floats, it will return the number of digits to the left of the decimal point, and only work on floats >0.1.)

Almost certainly there is an FPU instruction, not in the original x86 but certainly in an extension your CPU supports. You can test this by evaluating `log(N)` many times in a loop.

This is assuming you have the number stored as an int or float. If you have the number stored as a variable-length array using some library, this is O(1) time if the library precalculates the length of the array (the right thing to do), and O(N) time otherwise (bad libraries).

As with all float operations, accuracy can be a concern if you're really close to a transition 99-100, 999-1000, etc. As Steve Jessop points out in this answer's comments, you can determine if over/underestimating is okay according to the desired semantics. I might even say you have a bit of leeway: you could add/subtract something like 0.1 from N if somehow this failed for these transition numbers (there aren't that many numbers: you can manually test them all yourself to see if this is necessary).

Comment: Don't forget that log (0) is undefined!

Comment: @Skizz: hmm, perhaps I should mention that as a caveat, thank you.

Comment: `log10` is a better bet than calling `log` twice and dividing, even if the implementation can calculate `log(10)` at compile-time. `log10` shouldn't be any worse than a `log` followed by a division, and probably will be better, and may be more accurate. Accuracy is most vital when the input is a power of 10, since even a tiny inaccuracy in the negative direction is an out-by-one error.

Comment: @SteveJessop but there is no `log10`. There is an instruction for `y * log2(x)` though, that seems to fit the bill (with `y = 1/log2(10)`).

Comment: @harold: true (and there's an x86 instruction to load the constant `log(10)` too). There isn't an x86 instruction for `log10`, but I'm not wholly clear whether we're supposed to be writing C or x86 assembly. If C, then there is a `log10` function. Come to think of it, it's conceivable that `log(n) / log(10)` happens to be either accurate or an over-estimate for all 10-powers, but the implementation will do something slower and more accurate for doubles. In which case `log10` would be inefficient. You'd have to test the accuracy, if it turns out to be OK then `log10` is no longer a better bet.

Comment: I should point out that my main concern about anything involving doubles is accuracy, because for most purposes I can think of where you'd want to know how many base-10 digits a number requires, under-estimating is a serious bug. If an over-estimate is acceptable, then the fast solution is obvious: `return (CHAR_BIT * sizeof n) / 3 + 1` ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Main
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter the number : ");
    int n = in.nextInt ();
    double ans = 1 + Math.floor (Math.log (n) / Math.log (10));
    int intANS = (int) (ans);
    System.out.println ("No. of digits in " + n + " = " + intANS);
  }
}
```

// in JAVA

Answer (score -2):

```
class NumberOfDigits{

    public static void main(String ar[]){
        int n=99;
        System.out.println(""+(1+Math.floor(Math.log10(n))));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.